# Eclipse Synchronize Hotkeys

Tags: eclipse, synchronization, hotkeys

There is a button "Upload All Outgoing Changes" in Synchronize panel of eclipse. Any way to "click" it without mouse? There is no such action in prefs->general->keys

Comment: This is an only action I need to do with mouse. Thats why I want to find some way to do this. Maybe someone knows any macro plugins or some sort of?

Answer (score 1):

I created an Auto Hot Key file just for this. http://www.autohotkey.com/
I hope you like it!

```
; Eclipse Synchronize Override Upload
; AutoHotkey Version: 1.x
; Language:       English
; Platform:       Win9x/NT
; Author:        Taylor York <taylor@tyec.co>
;
; Script Function:
;   Upload Files to the Synchronize Window in Eclipse
;

;#NoTrayIcon
#SingleInstance force
DetectHiddenWindows, on

; the title starts with 
SetTitleMatchMode  2

SyncAndUpload()             ; Function
{
    ; Get to the Synchronize Tab
    Send {ALT down}         ; Hold Alt+Shift+Q down
    Send {SHIFT down}       ; Eclipse seemed to dislike pressing every key at once
    Send {Q down} 
    Send {Q up}
    Send {SHIFT up}
    Send {ALT up}
    Sleep, 250 ; wait 250 milliseconds
    Send y

    ; Click Override and Upload
    Send {Space}            ; When you go to the Synchronize tab, you have to select something. Space selects to top item
    Send {AppsKey}          ; "Right Click" / Context menu the item that is selected
    Send {o 2}          ; Press o twice (Override and Upload is the second O)
}


; Make sure we are in Eclipse, so we dont hijack other apps!
#IfWinActive, ahk_class SWT_Window0 
{   
    #IfWinActive, PHP           ;  Title starts with PHP (this is used so it only works in PHP mode.
    {
        ^T::
        {       
            KeyWait Control         ; Wait to run until all keys are let go
            KeyWait T

            SyncAndUpload()
            return
        }


        ^S::
        {
            KeyWait Control         ; Wait to run until all keys are let go
            KeyWait S

            Send ^S
            Sleep 250
            SyncAndUpload()
        }

    return
    }
return
}




;endofscript
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not exist and I think I know why: committing or updating should be a very conscious decision. So clicking the button promotes that kind of decision.

In general you can use Ctrl-Shift-L to see quick cheat sheet of shortcuts for currently opened views.