# Auto-upload on save

Tags: eclipse

I'm delveloping a PHP web application on my local PC. Whenever I save a file it would be handy if Eclipse could upload the file to my web server via FTP. Is Eclipse able to do that?? I think Netbeans offers such an option. At the moment I do the upload manually which is very annoying...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Eclipse [Target Management](http://eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/) (RSE). You can find a tutorial on [getting started](http://www.eclipse.org/tm/tutorial/index.php) page.

A big downside is that the quality of RSE's error messages range from okay-if-ambiguous to downright horrible (IBM-style 3 chars + 4 digits with no text message) so it's best if you know whatever protocol you're using well enough to guess what the error is without really needing the message to explain it to you.

Comment: When I use an FTP connection and work "directly" over FTP on the server I do not have the full functionality of Eclipse. I can't ctrl-click function names or class names to go the respective declaration. Thus, work on large projects is no big fun with RSE while it is comfortable for editing single files.

Comment: @Martin Another way to use it is its export feature:
Right click files/folders in Navigator -> Export, and then from the list of possible exporters choose "Remote file system" under "Remote Systems". You can save a *.rexpfd preset file so that if you need to export again later you can easily do the export by right clicking on the preset file and choosing "Export to Remote File System".

Answer (score 0):

So, after a whole lot of tries, I finally found something that works!

What you need to install is Eclipse WebDAV and FTP Support.  I have not found the eclipse update site, but this site has n archived version of it.  This allows you to sychronize your code with an FTP site.

http://eclipse.jcraft.com/

Then, to Automatically Upload On Save, you can use my Auto Hot Keys Script at:
[Eclipse Synchronize Hotkeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119239/eclipse-synchronize-hotkeys/7699168#7699168)